# How to enter values in brackets and numbers with a degree in C console

Tags: c, input, console, math.h

I have an array of **unsigned long long int** type, the values are entered in one line through the console, among the numbers there are (2^32-1)^2-1 and (2^32-1)^2+1.

How can I convert this to a natural number?

I tried to use:

```
scanf("%llu^%llu", &numbers[i], &degree[i]);
result[i] = pow(numbers[i], degree[i]);
```

but it only worked in a few cases

Comment: Please read [ask], provide a [mre], define the input, show the output you get and the output you expect; both, for several cases which work and several which do not work. Do not ignore the informative return value of `scanf()`. Output it, output also the scanned values. Init all your variable to recognisable special values. Read and fix all compiler warnings. Do not use the floatingpoint `pow()` for integers. I see your input description and your scanning format specifier in conflict.

Comment: Input with `fgets()` and parse the expression.

Comment: What @WeatherVane said. Eventually you hit the limits of `scanf`.